# Algebra increased speed travelling time problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

David notes that his trip to work takes t minutes at s miles per hour. If Tom increases his speed to $7/5s$, how long will his trip to work take?

$$t= \frac{d}{\frac{7}{5}s}$$

$$t= d*{\frac{5}{7s}}$$

If I were to get rid of $\frac{5}{7}$ by multiplying $\frac{7}{5}$ it becomes

$$\frac{7}{5}t= d*\frac{1}{s}$$

it doesnt make sense for the time to increase when the speed increases. Where is my mistake?

Comment: The new time would be $\frac{5t}{7}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$d=st=\frac75 s T$$

from which we can obtain the time T.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have $t_{\text{old}} = \frac{d}{s}$ and  $t_{\text{new}} = \frac57 \frac{d}{s}$, with the second being smaller than the first, as you might intuitively expect with a higher speed needing less time for the same distance.

In fact there is a units issue between hours and minutes, so if $d$ is measured in miles then perhaps you should say $t_{\text{old}} = 60\frac{d}{s}$ minutes while $t_{\text{new}}= \frac{300}{7}\frac{d}{s}$ minutes, which is again less.